# Compare strings and generate a suggestion in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of strings (names) which I would like to match to the database containing the same or variances of these names.
For each of the strings I want to match I can query the database, but this doesn’t seems to be efficient since the database is a fix set of names.

I was wondering if it was possible to have this match being done within PHP. I can use the levenshtein function in PHP, but I was wondering if there is anything more efficient.

The example I want to get to. On the left are all the strings I want to see if I have this in the database (or a small variance). Next to each I would like to have a pull down list containing the options that match closely.

- String 1 – pull down
- String 2 – pull down
- String 3 – pull down

What is the best approach to this? I have about 500-1000 strings for which I would like to get a suggestion/pull down menu.

With kind regards

Ralf

Comment: Give us a simple and short example of what you have and what you would get as a result.

Comment: as example:
The string is: Victoria, the suggestions could be: Hotel Victoria, Appartement Victoria. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps have a look at MySQL's full text search feature. I found this article on DevZone: http://devzone.zend.com/26/using-mysql-full-text-searching/

Comment: I don't believe this is the most effective way. Since this would mean, that on a page, I would run the query 500-1000 times against the same data set, with the only difference being the value it searches on in the full text search. Is there no quicker/better way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it client-side, jQuery UI Autocomplete is what you want. Not only that is very easy to configure it for your needs, but you can do it with only 1 query that would get all the strings and save it into a local list, the jQuery Autocomplete data source.

You can then register an onkeyup event for an input and the jQuery plugin will query the existing cached datasource(no more pressure for your server).

Check it out:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/